# SQLAlchemy aggregate count column most frequent value per group

Tags: python, postgresql, group-by, count, sqlalchemy

Supposing I have a table with columns *col1* and *col2*, I want to group my query of this table by *col1* but aggregate the most frequent value of *col2* for EACH resulting group.

For example I've tried:

```
session.query(A.col1, func.count(A.col2)).group_by(A.col1).all()
```

but this query results in the *overall* most-frequent value of *col2*, not the group's own most-frequent value of *col2*.

I've looked into several SO questions and documentation but every time the *func.count()* statement gets used with the *group_by* clause, they seem to interact with the very same column. How could I achieve the counting to apply on a per-group basis.

I've also looked at some suggested solutions involving *subqueries*, but that seems overly complex for such a simple problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this one plz

```
 session.query(A)
    .with_entities(A.col1, func.count(A.col2).label('count'))
    .group_by(A.col1).all()
```